# What are the configurations in Salesforce for client to access the Rest Service with http instead of https

Tags: rest, http, post, service

I have a Rest service(POST) that I expose publicly through sites. What are the configurations required in Salesforce for client to access the Rest Service with http instead of https.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is on this [Help page](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_creating_and_editing_sites.htm&language=en_US). From Setup, go to Develop > Sites and un-check "Require Secure Connections (HTTPS)".  You may also want to look at several of the adjacent pages in SF Help related to Sites including [this one](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_apex_methods_and_merge_fields.htm&language=en_US).